# My MySQL root password keep resetingwhen i restart my MacBook

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords, root, reset

I just bought the new MacBook Pro and I'm new with OSX, but I'd like to dev some web on it so I installed the AMP server, using this tutorial https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/.

But when the part of changing MySQL password comes, I can change it and connect to phpmyadmin but when I reset my Mac the root's password becomes again just like the one initialized by the install.

Futhermore, when I connect to phpmyadmin I do not have the privileges to create a database even if I'm connecting with 'root'.

This is going beyond frustration because I can't upload the database for my website.

Thanks

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I'll try this if anyone can figure this out for me :)

Answer (score 0):

you can manually reset the mysql password and make that permanent also. Follow below methods For MySQL configuration root password configuration for **Mac Sierra**

1. In terminal follow these steps

   - "**cd /usr/local/mysql/bin**" click enter button
   - "**sudo ./mysql -u root -p**" click enter and terminal will ask for 
     password and you need to copy paste the MySQL ROOT password which i 
     mentioned the step 1 and enter.
   - now you will be into mysql and if you want to change the ROOT 
     password then enter this command in terminal "**Alter user 
     'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your new password which you like 
     to change';**" enter and exit from terminal
2. Download phpmyadmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and extract the phpmyadmin file and rename it as **phpMyAdmin**into your WebServer/Documents folder **( /Library/WebServer/Documents/)**
3. Go to Terminal and enter the following command

   - **cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/** and click enter
   - **cd phpMyAdmin** and click enter
   - **sudo mkdir config** and click enter
   - **sudo chmod o+x config** and click enter
4. Go to Browser URL and enter the following **localhost/phpmyadmin/setup** and server set up page will be open and follow the below steps

   - Click on **New Server** button then navigate to authentication tab 
     and enter the **ROOT PASSWORD** & click apply button
   - At bottom of overview page you can find Download button and click 
     that and **config.inc.php** file will be downloaded
   - copy paste the **config.inc.php** file inside your **phpMyAdmin** 
     folder